# Compatibility between realm iOS and realm Xamarin iOS && realm Java and realm Xamarin Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, realm

In my company we have 2 native iOS/Android libraries using Core Data and ORMLite. We would like to replace these ORMs by realm, but we have few questions about compatibilities between the different realm libraries.

- Is Realm Objective-C compatible with Realm Xamarin iOS (realm dotnet?) ?
- Is Realm Objective-C compatible with Realm Swift ?
- Is Realm Java compatible with Realm Xamarin Android (realm dotnet?) ?

By compatible I mean, can I make a Xamarin app using realm dotnet to write some data in realm, and then query that data from a native obj-c/swift library using realm (that library being referenced by the xamarin app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the Realm bindings use the same underlying database technology under the hood, so yes that is possible, and it is also one of our primary design goals.

The API's might differ slightly across languages, but you should definitely be able to access the data.

The only requirement is just that the model classes have to match across the languages, since those are what defines the schema.

Comment: So if I have in the native library a model class A (in obj-c / swift or java), I can make it public and use the Xamarin binding system to use it from Xamarin without having to duplicate that class in C#, right?

Comment: No, you would have to duplicate the model class in the language you want to use it in.

Comment: Hm I don't really understand why. Since xamarin does the binding for us, if I do myModelObject.myProperty = "abc"; xamarin will mimic a [myModelObject setMyProperty: @"abc"]; so behind the scenes realm is called by the model right?

Comment: Well, you need Realm model classes for their respective languages

Comment: Our build systems on the various platforms does a lot of magic behind the scenes, which is why you cannot use your own conversion tools for those classes

Comment: @ChristianMelchior thanks for the explanation, i'll take a look at the build scripts (which are part of the open source part I guess).

Comment: @ChristianMelchior last question: is it for that reason (things happening during build) that swift and obj-c api are indicated as "not exchangeable" in the docs ?

Comment: Yes, and Java and .NET have similar build type things happening